# Buttons in a UICollectionView don't receive touch events

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've been looking around for a while now but can't seem to work out how to stop the collection view cells from consuming the touch events.

I need the touch events to be passed down into the respective cells so that the buttons within the cells can be pressed. I was thinking i might need to work out how to disable the UICollectionView's didSelectCellAtIndexFunction?

I've also seen this as a potential solution: collectionView.cancelsTouchesInView = false

Also this link might help someone answer my question: [How to add tap gesture to UICollectionView , while maintaining cell selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365971/how-to-add-tap-gesture-to-uicollectionview-while-maintaining-cell-selection)

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Also I should add: my buttons are added to a view that is in turn added to the cell's contentView. My code is done all programatically and so I am not using interface Builder at all.

Comment: make sure your button's user interaction is enable and it is not covered by any other view or some transparent object !

Comment: check if button is not out of collectionViewCell's bounds

Comment: buttons are in cell's bounds @mkowal87

Comment: You don't have to do anything special to get a button to register a tap in a collection view cell. You need to show the code you're using to create the buttons and add them to the cells.

Answer (score 1):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false // all cell items you do not want to be selectable
    }
```

Assuming all buttons are connected to the same selector, you need a way to differentiate which cell's button has been clicked. One of the ways for finding out the button's cell's index is:

```
func buttonPressed(button: UIButton) {
    let touchPoint = collectionView.convertPoint(.zero, fromView: button)
    if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(touchPoint) {
        // now you know indexPath. You can get data or cell from here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph but I'm not using NIB's, my collectionView, cells, and buttons are made all programatically and my views are definitely added to the contentView

Comment: then try overriding the UICollectionViewDelegate's collectionView(_:shouldSelectItemAt:) method and return false on items where you do not want the collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:) to be called.

Answer (score 1):

Try on your cell.

```
self.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```