# Add a tap event to CollectionViewCell while passing Cell data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to add a tap event to my `CollectionViewCell` and to pass there my `cell` with the data it has. How can I achieve this?
Should this event be handled by my `ViewController` or by `CollectionViewCell`?

My `ViewController`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imgImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.url = "xhini"

    return cell
}
```

My `CollectionViewCell`:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgImage: UIImageView!
    var url: String = "url"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement `UICollectionViewDelegate` and then you can use following method in the `ViewController` to react to selecting a cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    // do stuff with image, or with other data that you need
}
```

Don't forget to set the delegate where you set a data source:

```
collectionView.dataSource = self
// add this line:
collectionView.delegate = self
```

**UPDATE**

Or if you are using a storyboards, you want to set it using storyboards the same way as you set a dataSource for the `dataSource` of the `tableView`:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Your `tap` gesture recognizer cancels event for the collection view, so to deal with this, just uncomment the line `tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false`, and it will work:

```
    //Looks for single or multiple taps.
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Comment: I add a simple print statement and it does nothing. You mean I should attach here a tap event or smth?

Comment: @rexhin dont forget to set the delegate to self:  `collectionView.delegate = self`

Comment: where  should I  add this line? inside my `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    // do stuff with image, or with other data that you need
}`

Comment: @rexhin no, not at all. I think `viewDidLoad` is the best place.. find where you set the data source (where you have line `collectionView.dataSource = self`), and add it there

Comment: @rexhin : I suggest you go through Apple docs or perhaps a good UICollectionView tutorial or for that matter, tutorial on delegates as to how they are used and where to set them.

Comment: I do not have that line. I do not have a `collectionView` instance at all. I have just an array of UIImages. if you want to check my full project you can check it here: https://gitlab.com/rexhin/ios-kida.git @MilanNosáľ

Comment: @rexhin add it to `viewDidLoad`, or add the delegate through the storyboard by linking the `delegate` of the collection view to the `viewController` (the same way you did with dataSource) - I'll update the answer to include a screenshot

Comment: @rexhin : As per the code you have shared there is no UICollectionView. I only guess I can make is that you have directly bind the collectionView from storyboard without creating IBOutlet for that. So there are two ways : 1. Set delegate and dataSource from storyboard. 2. Assign IBOutlet to UICollectionView and link it to storyboard and then set delegate and dataSource as Milan has suggested

Comment: @rexhin I updated the question, just link it using storyboards

Comment: I have something like that but I do not have an instance for that on my file. something like `collectionView`. I updated my question with an image of what i currently have @Nitish @Milan

Comment: @rexhin it seems that the delegate is linked.. still not getting that "tap" text printed?

Comment: nope, i have a print there but i get nothing, `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("tap")
    }`

Comment: @rexhin : Found out the issue. Check my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. that was funny. the line was already there but commented out

Answer (score 1):

I saw your code which you shared in the above answer by @Milan and figured out the reason.
You have added a tap gesture on `viewDidLoad` of **ViewController** :

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

This makes the `UICollectionView's` `didSelectItemAt` not getting called.
So comment this code and it should work.
For this gesture, you have to find another approach

Comment: you recommend him to break other functionality to fix his current issue.. how does this help?

Comment: Thank you but I have to accept @MilanNosáľ answer because of this reason. :)

Comment: If you want to get awarded the accepted answer, you can have it. I solved OP's question. Regarding gesture, I would be happy to help if he faces the issue. BTW, it should be OP who should be worried :)

Comment: @rexhin : Not a problem. Milan's answer was absolutely correct from implementation point of view and should be awarded. Glad I could help.

Comment: Those lines you told me to remove are used to close the keyboard. If the user clicks everywhere else except the keyboard the keyboard is closed.

Comment: @rexhin : This should help you. Check the accepted answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365971/how-to-add-tap-gesture-to-uicollectionview-while-maintaining-cell-selection

Comment: Yes, I had that line there before asking this question but for some reason it was commented out